# Docusign API "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER"

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

I have a problem with the DocuSign API premium plan. The first signer can sign the contract which we are generating via API without any problem, but when it comes to the second signer, in the same envelope ID we receive this error:

```
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '155', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '6fd068b4-9f2d-41a7-bd01-351e2676f438', 'Date': 'Tue, 15 Jun 2021 08:50:45 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': 'BIGipServerpool_SE2_NA4_API=!JACGQDicHt+h1TK0bOlB09wl7Vsgf/x6uU4IHjwxIL8hJpHlxDwjr2QgIA/ku3g50UYGhRu67eFbSA==; path=/; Httponly; Secure'})
HTTP response body: b'{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A value was not found for parameter \'userName\'."}'
```

Any help?

P.S we are using:

python 3.x - docusign-esign 3.10.0 SDK

Answer (score 0):

Your app/integration is making a call to get a recipient view, something like this:

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/4e268385-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2ada7dc696fd/envelopes/ca166b41-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c3bcfa2d0639/views/recipient
```

This is used for [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/), to get back a URL to sign by your app.
You must provide a **userName** to this call in the body of the call/JSON, but you're using the Python SDK so [the code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eg001_embedded_signing/controller.py) looks like this:

```
# 3. Create the Recipient View request object
recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
    authentication_method=authentication_method,
    client_user_id=envelope_args["signer_client_id"],
    recipient_id="1",
    return_url=envelope_args["ds_return_url"],
    user_name=envelope_args["signer_name"],
    email=envelope_args["signer_email"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But we receive the same error.

Comment: Based on the DocuSign document, we need to use username or userID:  "Specifies the user ID of the recipient. You can use with user ID or email and user name to identify the recipient. If user ID is used and a client user ID is provided, the value in the userId property must match a recipient ID (which can be retrieved with a GET recipients call) for the envelope. If a user ID is used and a clientUser ID is not provided, the user ID match the user ID of the authenticating user."   But we do not receive username or user ID from DocuSign at all!

Comment: You have two signers, one works ok, one does not, right?
the reason is that for the second signer you don't provide the correct information. 
I cannot find out what the information is, but if you share your entire envelope including the various roles and recipients - I can try to help. Or you can contact support.

Comment: userName or user_name is the name of the signer like "John Doe"

Comment: you also need to have the client_user_id that matches what you entered when you created the envelope for this recipient.